# How to get proper text-color-highlighting for Fortran 90 in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: fortran, sublimetext2, fortran90

There are a couple of links on sublime forum, on how to get Sublime Text 2 to work with Fortran 90 here http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=770, but they don't quite seem to work as the comment identifier "!" is not treated well.

I quickly assembled a solution using the original suggested Punchcard.tmLanguage file and modifying the first block in dictionary to treat "!" as comment (available here: https://gist.github.com/4209445).

Sublime Text 2 is a great text editor and having it support Fortran might be helpful for many people in Theoretical physics and Finance. So if anyone knows a better solution, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The plugin at [the fortran.tmBundle](https://github.com/textmate/fortran.tmbundle) works for me. I created a `Fortran` subfolder in `Packages` and put all the files in the tmBundle there (not just the `.tmLanguage` files). It selects Fortran - Punchcard as the default type for `.for` and Fortran - Modern for `.f90` files. These both treat `!` just fine on my system - what problem are you having?

Comment: Thanks! I used .tmLanguage files only, that was the problem.

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept the answer (the tick mark next to the arrow) if it solved your problem.

Comment: the `Packages` folder can be accessed through menu `Preferences`>`Browse packages`

Answer (score 7):

I also use Fortran (Modern) with Sublime Text (now I'm using version 3) and there was just a little glitch handling comments. Look at this example:

[image]

As you can see, the second line starts with an exclamation mark, but it's not recognized. But if I start the first line with "! " (including a space), then everything works:

[image]

If I put a dash after the ! of the second line, it reconizes it as a comment, but the problem goes to the third line:

[image]

I don't understand the language of the syntax file, but I've looked at the [MinimalFortran package](https://github.com/315234/MinimalFortran) to fix this (this package works great and can be installed using Package Control, but it misses lots of syntaxes). I just changed the

```
<string>!-</string>
```

to

```
<string>[!]</string>
```

on the "Fortran - Modern.tmLanguage" file and it all worked:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [Minimal Fortran](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MinimalFortran). Been using it for a couple of months and can vouch for it. Easy to install using Package Control as well.